# Amazon RDS MySQL support for JSON functions

Tags: mysql, json, amazon-web-services

I'm interested in using these functions in my Amazon RDS with MySQL instance:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html

But looks like they are not available:

```
FUNCTION mysql.JSON_CONTAINS does not exist
```

It can be because the MySQL version Amazon is running:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html

> "Unless otherwise indicated, the JSON functions were added in MySQL
>   5.7.8."

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
innodb_version 5.6.19
```

Any solution for MySQL JSON support in Amazon RDS?

Comment: doesn't your question answer itself?

Comment: @tedder42 the point that I may found the cause of the problem doesn't mean that there is not a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is a feature added in MySQL version 5.7.8. The latest version of MySQL that RDS currently supports is 5.6.23. The only solution is to wait for Amazon to add support for MySQL 5.7.8.

By the way you can look in your RDS console to see what version of MySQL your RDS instance is using.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon just has launched [support for MySQL 5.7](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/02/amazon-rds-now-supports-mysql-5-7/)